# Cursor point in form

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I want to get the cursor point in the form and not in the screen, i understand i need to use:

```
        Point ptCursor = Cursor.Position;
        ptCursor = PointToClient(ptCursor);
```

The issue is that i used this in a method that work on different thread, and it give me this error message:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

why i get this error msg?
can i used this lines in a method that run on thread?
how can i call a method to run on form thread in couple of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispatch the PointToClient operation on the GUI thread:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => ptCursor = PointToClient(ptCursor)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access you UI level via `Invoke` method.

```
        Point ptCursor;

        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            ptCursor = Cursor.Position;
            ptCursor = PointToClient(ptCursor);
        }));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the form and call invoke().

like

```
 Point ptCursor = Cursor.Position;
 Action action = () => ptCursor  = PointToClient(ptCursor);
 this.Invoke(action);
```